# Running a 32-bit window service which loads a 32-bit dll as a 64-bit service

Tags: .net, 32bit-64bit, windows64, corflags, linq-to-excel

Here's the situation -

A window service which I am coding uses Linq2Excel, which insist the invoking application to be complied against x86.

However, the window service is to be installed on a 64-bit Windows server.

Using corflags, I am able to get the 32-bit window service to install. However, it'll refuse to load Linq2Excel. Here's the exception in all its glory:

```
Exception occurs: Could not load file or assembly 'LinqToExcel, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. 
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

What is the solution to get this service working? (Changing the server to 32-bit is not going to happen, using Linq2Excel is a must)

Comment: did you ever solve this problem, @Extrakun ? I'm having similar issues here...

Comment: No. I have to force Linq2Excel to use the latest Windows Access Database Engine (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255) so that I can compile it as a 64-bit DLL.

Comment: @Extrakun: did you build your service with "Any CPU" target or x86 target ?

Comment: I believe it is Any CPU.

Answer (score 1):

If everything is 32 bit it should work fine on 64dit machine, but 32bit app could not load 64bit dll, you can make out of process call using WCF or whatever

Comment: It's the 64-bit machine being unable to load the 32-bit window service.